# Ionic5 / Angular 9 Google maps fails on device or Chrome mobile emulation

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic5

I have set up a Google map in my Ionic 5 app and it works fine the first time I go there. But if I hit the back button and return to this map or any other map; I only see the map markers but not the map.

my Component code looks like:

```
export class MapsPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(GoogleMapComponent, { static: true }) _GoogleMap: GoogleMapComponent;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: 52, lng: 6}
  };
  loadingElement: any;

  constructor(
    private loadingController: LoadingController,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.mapSet) {
      this._GoogleMap.$mapReady.subscribe(map => {
        this.map = map;
      });
    }
    this.createLoader();
  }

  async createLoader() {
    this.loadingElement = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Trying to get your current location...'
    });
  }
}
```

My template looks like:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="tours"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{tour.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-fab vertical="top" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="geolocateMe()" color="secondary">
      <ion-icon name="locate"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
  <google-map  [mapOptions]="mapOptions"></google-map>
</ion-content>
```

[EDIT] I had originally posted that this was due to the back button; but it seems it is only an issue with mobile emulation (Chrome) or on a real device. When I run in Chrome (not in mobile mode); it works fine. Also, it works in Firefox whether in mobile mode or not.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: Sorry, I gave up trying to get that working, although this package is the code which does not work: https://ionicthemes.com/product/ionic5-full-starter-app-pro-version. The people who distribute that package have verified that the code does not work and are investigating. I have given up trying to get it working and switched to this plugin: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps

Comment: Thanks for the update, I see so it's the library's own bug. Glad you found another one that does work! :)